# Primefaces p:selectBooleanButton ignorando Converter

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Estou tentando fazer com que um `p:selectBooleanButton` seja utilizado para selecionar o status de um formulário de cadastro. O valor do atributo no modelo é um `Enum` com dois valores que podem ser traduzidos como `True` ou `False`. No entanto, após escrever um `Converter` customizado e tentar setar para o componente utilizar, recebo um `IllegalArgumentException` como se o componente tentasse converter diretamente o valor para o `Enum`, ignorando completamente o `Converter`.

**Nota:** Se eu trocar o componente por um `p:inputText` ou `p:inputSwitch` a conversão ocorre normalmente. Não faço ideia do que fazer pra solucionar isso. Sera que é um bug do `p:selectBooleanButton` e não tem como usar um  `Converter` customizado?.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert H of type class br.com.dbsystem.propulsor.entities.seguranca.Usuario$Situacao to class java.lang.Boolean

EDIT: Estou utilizando:

- Payara Server 4.1.2.174
- Eclipselink 2.6.4
- OmniFaces 2.6.8
- JSF (Mojarra) 2.2.16
- PrimeFaces 6.1
- PrimeFaces Extensions 6.1

Segue o código e stacktrace:

Enum:

```
public enum Situacao {
        H("Habilitado"),
        D("Desabilitado");

        private final String label;

        private Situacao(String label) {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public String getLabel() {
            return label;
        }

    }
```

Componente no form:

```
<p:selectBooleanButton 
          id="sitUsuSis" 
          onLabel="#{msg.btn_habilitado}" 
          offLabel="#{msg.btn_desabilitado}" 
          converter="booleanToSituacaoConverter"
          value="#{formSegurancaUsuarioExternoBean.entity.sitUsuSis}" />
```

Converter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "booleanToSituacaoConverter")
public class BooleanToSituacaoConverter implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string) {

    System.out.println("BooleanToSituacaoConverter.getAsObject");
    System.out.println("string = " + string);

    Boolean bool = Boolean.valueOf(string);

    if (bool) {
        return Usuario.Situacao.H;
    }

    return Usuario.Situacao.D;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object entity) {
    System.out.println("BooleanToSituacaoConverter.getAsString");
    System.out.println("entity = " + entity);

    if (entity instanceof Usuario.Situacao) {
        switch ((Usuario.Situacao) entity) {
            case H:
                return Boolean.TRUE.toString();
            default:
                return Boolean.FALSE.toString();
        }
    }

    return Boolean.FALSE.toString();
}

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
GRAVE:   Error Rendering View[/sistema/seguranca/usuarios_externo/incluir.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /sistema/seguranca/usuarios_externo/incluir.xhtml @61,114 value="#{formSegurancaUsuarioExternoBean.entity.sitUsuSis}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert H of type class br.com.dbsystem.propulsor.entities.seguranca.Usuario$Situacao to class java.lang.Boolean
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:293)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:94)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:58)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectbooleanbutton.SelectBooleanButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectBooleanButtonRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectbooleanbutton.SelectBooleanButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectBooleanButtonRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:308)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:271)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:132)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:119)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1692)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at br.com.dbsystem.propulsor.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:79)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLessToExtension(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:184)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLess(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:141)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLess(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:127)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:88)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert H of type class br.com.dbsystem.propulsor.entities.seguranca.Usuario$Situacao to class java.lang.Boolean
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingExpressionFactory.coerceToType(ForwardingExpressionFactory.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingExpressionFactory.coerceToType(ForwardingExpressionFactory.java:38)
    at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.el.lang.EvaluationContext.convertToType(EvaluationContext.java:166)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert H of type class br.com.dbsystem.propulsor.entities.seguranca.Usuario$Situacao to class java.lang.Boolean
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToBoolean(ELSupport.java:191)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:409)
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:85)
    ... 96 more

ADVERTÊNCIA:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert H of type class br.com.dbsystem.propulsor.entities.seguranca.Usuario$Situacao to class java.lang.Boolean
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToBoolean(ELSupport.java:191)
    at com.sun.el.lang.ELSupport.coerceToType(ELSupport.java:409)
    at com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.coerceToType(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingExpressionFactory.coerceToType(ForwardingExpressionFactory.java:38)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingExpressionFactory.coerceToType(ForwardingExpressionFactory.java:38)
    at javax.el.ELContext.convertToType(ELContext.java:478)
    at com.sun.el.lang.EvaluationContext.convertToType(EvaluationContext.java:166)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:229)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:293)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:94)
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:58)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectbooleanbutton.SelectBooleanButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectBooleanButtonRenderer.java:63)
    at org.primefaces.component.selectbooleanbutton.SelectBooleanButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectBooleanButtonRenderer.java:56)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabContent(TabViewRenderer.java:308)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeContents(TabViewRenderer.java:271)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:132)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:71)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:72)
    at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:49)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:456)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:119)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1692)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at br.com.dbsystem.propulsor.filters.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:79)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLessToExtension(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:184)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLess(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:141)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLess(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:127)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:88)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: se o converter não esta como BEAN vc deve chamar ele como classe, acredito que esse seja o erro, tente chamar pelo nome da classe como por exemplo converter = "br.github.BooleanToSituacaoConverter"

Comment: @WeslleyBarbosa Não é o caso.. como expliquei ali, se eu trocar pra um inputText o converter é chamado quando carrega a view. Parece que é ignorado só com o selectBooleanButton, inclusive com um inputSwitch que também funciona com booleano, o converter funciona normalmente.

Comment: Não seria o caso de usar um outro componente, como o `SelectOneMenu`, por exemplo? Sendo que o `sitUsuSis` é do tipo `Situacao`, portanto poderia receber 3 valores: `H`, `D` e `null`?

Comment: Na verdade não amigo. Este código utiliza uma base de dados antiga, (uns 20 anos..) e por motivos que desconheço acharam que seria uma boa ideia deixar esse valor como `null` em algumas situações, o que não faz sentido na verdade, já que a situação seria apenas H(habilitado) e D(desabilitado). Dessa forma os registros novos não deverão ter essa possibilidade. Acabei por deixar utilizando um inputSwitch já que estava funcionando com o converter corretamente. Obrigado.